# display image and text from array on react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm new on react native. I want to display images and text from array.
When I'm trying to extract image from my app, It doesn't work, the images are not displayed.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Animaux",
    data: ["Poissons","Crevettes","Escargots"],
    image: [require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png'),require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png'),require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')]
  }
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const ImageType = ({ image }) => (
  <View style={styles.image}>
    <Image source={image}/>
  </View>
);

export default class InventaireScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          sections={DATA}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item, image }) => 
            <View >
              <ImageType source={image}/>
              <Item title={item} />
            </View>
            }
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{title}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

the images are not displaying.
Could you please tell me where I'm wrong ?
Thanks.

EDIT :

I modified my array like that :

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Poissons",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
  {
    title: "Crevettes",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
  {
    title: "Escargots",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
];
```

I try to extract data using render:

```
export default class InventaireScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          sections={DATA}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
              <ImageType image={item.image}/>
              <Item title={item.data} />
            </View>
            }
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to display section title using title parameter, an image using image source, and a text using data parameter of my array.

I have this error

```
 ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.length')
``
```

Comment: Try to console the item variable in renderItem and see what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting renderItem.

```
renderItem={({ item }) => 
        <View >
          <ImageType image={item.image}/>
          <Item title={item.title} />
        </View>
        }
```

and keyExtractor.

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title + index}
```

this keyExtractor will only take the title and index instead of the full object.

and data format.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Poissons",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
  {
    title: "Crevettes",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
  {
    title: "Escargots",
    image: require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')
  },
];
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I tried that but I have no changes. Nothing is displayed for the image and text. But If I replace item.title by item the text is ok but the image is still not displaying.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the data format. It's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Statement

```
 renderItem={({ item, image }) =>
```

the second argument should be index,

Instead of '**image**' it should be '**index**'

```
 renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
```

In order to fetch parameter 'image' from your array you will need to change your code like below :

```
<View >
  <ImageType image={item.image}/>
  <Item title={item.title} />
</View>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I tried also your solution. Nothing is displayed for the image and text. But If I replace item.title by item the text is ok but the image is still not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

you data object should be an array of objects to map through it, like

```
var Data = [{title:"Poissons",image:require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')},{title:"Crevettes",image:require('../assets/icon_aquarium_style.png')},{...},{...}]
```

and then in render item

```
 {({ item }) => 
       <View >
         <ImageType image={item.image}/>
         <Item title={item.title} />
       </View>
      }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post. I edited my post using your recommendation but I also no have text and image, only section titles

Comment: Can you try putting just the relative paths in image field in DATA without require() and use require like <Image source={require(item.image)} />